# Compare two cells in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a problem with a IF function in excel.

I have a two cells:

- D1 Aug'21 (=D1) return Aug'21
- C5 Aug/21 (=C5) return 44,287

and i wanna compare both cells but how? I can't change any format of these cells.

i want result something like that:
=IF(D1=C5, "True", "False") => True

Comment: =C5=D5 will return true or false

Answer (score 1):

Incase of you can't format any cells, might you still can use `TEXT` formula to manipulate the C5 to become **same format** as D1.

```
=IF(D1=TEXT(C5,"MMM'yy"), "True", "False")
```